# Can I install SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition if SQL Server 2008 Express already installed?`

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

On my windows xp machine I already have SQL Server 2008 R2 Advanced Express edition installed.

Now I want to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition. Is it possible to both will be installed on the same machine? Can I install SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition?

Answer (score 4):

[From here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143694%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> SQL Server supports multiple instances of the Database Engine, Analysis Services, and Reporting Services on the same computer

Comment: H all when i install sqlserver 2008 standard edition its giving a error message , i choosedn new instance

Comment: Previous release of microsoft visual studio 2008 in installaton rules

Comment: An important point is made at the link below:  "... the shared components are upgraded to the latest version, in this case SQL Server 2008 R2."  You can have both, but the install of R2 will affect your existing installation... so therefore you'll want to do it first in a test enviroment, and check if your existing apps are affected.  Link here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210714(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://paresh-sqldba.blogspot.de/2011/04/can-we-install-multiple-versions-of-sql.html Referring to this blogpost it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: yes

I have both versions installed. your sqlexpress is propably installed as a named instance that you connect to with "\sqlexpress" in the connection string